# Windows Phone Control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I have a simple question :
the following control is a user control or can i find it in the Control Library provided by Microsoft ?

[image: Control]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called ToggleSwitch and you can find it in the [Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

**Edit**

You need to install Silverlight toolkit and add a reference to Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll in your project.

Map the namespace:

```
xmlns:toolbox="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Use control:

```
<toolbox:ToggleSwitch/>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i find the ToggleButton but not the ToggleSwitch : i just install the MSI and then restart VS 2010, and try to add the ToggleSwitch control